# Changing window size using the expression blend visual designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I am having some trouble figuring out how exactly I resize my WPF form in blend using the visual designer. Any controls I have no issue resizing them, although with a form the only way I can do so is by setting the xaml code behind to increase it, it is the only way I can even make the form activly selected so I can do anything with it. I must be missing something crucial.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Version of Visual Studio (Blend implicit)?

Comment: I am using Expression Blend 4. Not the VS Plugin. I have no issues in VS though. I don't really understand why they had to make blends basic features different from visual studio.

Comment: Blend is very powerful when we talk about customization.

Comment: @SJD That is why I am learning it, I am just not sure why the most basic of features couldn't be the same as almost every IDE out there. Although I do understand it is a design tool.

Comment: Expression Blend's purpose is to give to user the possibility to use high-level features but also the user can easily fiddle with low-level features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Expression Blend 4 (as you said) you should:

- Select the Window element in Objects and Timeline
- In the Layout section of the Properties panel
- Set the *Width* and *Height* as you want.

Comment: I had to undock the O/T panel for be able to select it the Window Elemnent, but when I did I was able to follow those steps. The height width box is different but cool, with being able to change it by dragging the cursor inside the textbox up/down/left/right to change the value. Thank you.